# Jupyter Notebooks: button onclick doesn't work within running notebook

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I've got a means of simultaneously opening several source documents in separate tabs using `IPython.display.Javascript` to help streamline error-analysis workflow.

```
# This opens all links in new tabs upon cell execution

def open_all(links):
    # Set up onclick function
    javascript = "\n".join(['window.open("{}");'.format(link) for link in links])
    return javascript

js = open_all_dockets(links)
display(Javascript(js))
```

What I would really like to do is be able to **tie the opening of these links in new tabs to a button**. This would allow the notebook user to execute all the cells and still **control which set of source documents to open with a click**.

The problem is this only works when once the notebook is rendered to HTML.

```
# The button opens links in new tabs *only* once the notebook is rendered to HTML

def open_all_button(links):
    # Set up onclick function
    onclick =  "function open() {\n"
    onclick += "\n".join([" "*4 + 'window.open("{}");'.format(link) for link in links])
    onclick += "}\n"
    # Create button
    button = "element.append('<button onclick={}>one click open source docs</button>')".format('"open()"')
    # Assemble JS
    javascript = onclick + button
    return javascript

display(Javascript(open_all_button(links)))
```

How can I get this to work in a running notebook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a mess around and this seems to work for both a live notebook and when output as html. I'm guessing that having the `open()` function defined separately was messing things up, so we just define it within the `onclick` property of the button itself.

```
# The button opens links in new tabs *only* once the notebook is rendered to HTML
import IPython.display as display
def open_all_button(links):
    # Set up onclick function
    onclick = "".join(['window.open("{}");'.format(link) for link in links])
    # Create button
    javascript = "element.append('<button onclick=" + onclick +">one click open source docs</button>')"
    return javascript

display.Javascript(open_all_button(["https://www.google.com","https://www.google.co.uk"]))
```